# htaccess to nginx converter

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

My htaccess code:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In nginx config I've tried this but it didn't work

```
location /mysite{
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mysite/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Anyone can help me, tks so much. 
p/s: I've tried http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/ and http://winginx.com/htaccess, but both of them can't help

Comment: You can try this. http://www.anilcetin.com. Seems to spit out some code

Comment: tks @PanamaJack, I've tried anilcetin.com, but it seem not work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use nginx and don't know it well enough myself.